# Monotone sequence bounded by two monotone sequences converging with multiplying $t$ converges with multiplying $t$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, brownian-motion, monotone-functions

I want to show that $\lim_{t\to \infty}t f(t) $ exists and the limit is in $(0, \infty)$ for some function $f$. Now I manage to find two bounds for $f$ in which there exists $M, m, R>0$ such that for $t$ big enough:

$$ \frac{m}{t - R} \leq f(t) \leq \frac{M}{t - R}.$$

So if the limit exists then trivially it's in $(0, \infty)$. However, I'm not sure how to prove $tf(t)$ converges. I know that $f$ is a monotone function and have the two bounds above. Does it suffice for the proof or I need to find further results?

(p.s $f$ is the probability of some $2$-Brownian motion hitting a ball of radius $e^{-t}$ centered at origin before exiting some domain $D$. And I have no clue on how it behaves. Any hints on its property will also be much appreciated).

Comment: Take $f$ such that $f(t):=\frac{\sin(t)+2}{t-1}$. Then $\frac1{t-1}\leq f(t)\leq\frac3{t-1}$ for $t>1$. But $\lim_{t\to\infty}tf(t)$ does not exist.

Comment: yeah but the $f$ you gave is not monotone right? What If I also have  the condition that the function $f$ is monotone decreasing